# How to study for the GRE exam? (e.g.memorizing 3500 words, Math problems, AWA)

Tags: phd, united-states, gre

I am so worried about the GRE exam! I have not any experience about it, but need to take it in order to do my PhD in the USA. So far I prepared a vocabulary notebook and wrote the definitions of 3500 words. Now, I am thinking of how to memorize those words in a short time. Moreover, I need to study for the Math and analytical writing sections.

Comment: What field are you applying in? Depending on the field, the different scores may be weighted differently, and so you might want to focus your efforts on the section(s) that will matter most for getting accepted.

Comment: While this is off-topic, anyone who wants to prepare for the GRE should *first* go directly to the GRE source and use their free materials, especially POWERPREP software: https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/powerprep/ You can take a test for free, simulating your own test environment, and it will even give you an estimated score (not counting written/verbal) which is quite reliably close to the score you'd actually get if you had taken the GRE that day. You can then decide how to focus your prep from there.

Comment: running the risk of being perceived as self-advertising, [my deck](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1346912511) seems to have a high receive from users who learn the GRE test. So far it is the top result if you search for `gre anki`, and on average it has 10 downloads each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend Magoosh. I used their vocabulary app while I was walking around campus for a couple months and by the time the exam came I was thoroughly prepared. They also have a pay-for-service learning course which is good to review the material you've forgotten since high school. I am a fairly math oriented person going into the life sciences so I did not do too much of the math portion of Magoosh but the writing section was fairly useful and the english section was great. Knock 'em Dead!

Comment: [Magoosh GRE prep](https://www.techpoweredmath.com/magoosh-gre-gmat-review/) is particularly useful if you are looking to do a self-paced, self-study program. They don't currently offer live instruction like some of their competitors, but they also are quite a bit cheaper than Princeton Review or Kaplan. They also offer a free iOS and Android apps for practicing GRE vocabulary words.

Answer (score 0):

For the vocab you could  download this flashcard deck https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2430987595 and the software anki. It's a spaced repetition software with a little bit of a learning curve, but once you get it down it is highly effective. Or you could search memrise for a few gre decks.

I just bought a GRE workbook. I have yet to crack it open, so i cant review it. But it has a lot of quanatative questions that mimic the GRE. So a work book and some flashcard software would be your best bet.

Good luck!